# Magento : Fastest way to update a product attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, product-attribute, best-practice

I'm looking for the fastest and reliable method for mass attribute update.
Below are the methods am aware of but I don't know with which I should go.

```
$store_id = 0;
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($product_id),
    array('attribute_code' => $attribute_code),
    $store_id
);
```

or

```
$product->setData($attribute_code, 1234); 
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, $attribute_code);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The fastest way is to do direct selects and inserts/updates in the database, but that's not the safest. You can easily break stuff.

I use the `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(...)` approach.
It is fast, you can use it to bulk update product attributes, you can update an attribute value for a specific store.
I think it covers most of the cases needed.

Comment: thanks marius i was expecting your response, btw your ultimate module creator is kool

Comment: it is not actually the fastest choose ... check my answer below

Comment: @Fra How is your method faster? It involves `load`. that anything but fast. For example, in method 2, the first line with the product load is useless. You are not using `$product` anywhere.

Comment: @Fra. When you downvote someone's answer it's a nice thing to state a reason. What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I gave a reason: it is not the fastest method. So you are not answering the question ( alias quality of the answer is low )

Comment: I could say the same thing for your answer...it's not the fastest way. direct SQL queries are the fastest way. I don't think your reason is enough for downvoting. But you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: updateAttributes are calling lot (a lot lot ) of queries when used to update the price for one product... I want to do it for 30_products, which takes in my developer machine 30s. Is that expected from updateAttributes ? If its expected i am trying to update EAV tables directly.. Is that a good idea ?

Comment: I used this to update hundreds of products at once an it did not take 30 seconds. Maybe you need to disable the auto index rebuil but not sure. And for EAV tables edit it is possible but you really have to know what you are doing.

Comment: Is it possible that `load` inst the bottleneck here? Guess a full product `save()` would make it slower. I was suprised about xhprof result ... do you have any ideas? (use `updateAttributes` also very often, but now im not sure about that)

Comment: One thing is sure. You cannot have a save without a load. If you do, you will lose data.I have used before `updateAttributes` and it seems to be the best speed-low risk trade off. You want speed, do direct db inserts. It's as fast as it gets but one simple mistake and you are screwed.

Comment: @Marius regarding your doubt about why that is not the fastest method you can review my answer and also sv3n answer that contains some benchmark ... those shows your method is the slowest out of the 3 so  yours it is not the correct answer ... why this happens ? because updateAttribute() triggers reindex :)

Answer (score 32):

Actually there are 3 ways to update an attribute on a product without save the full product.
Depending on the code/requirements one can be faster that the other.

**Method 1:**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$resource = $product->getResource();

$product->setData($attribue_code, $value);
$resource->saveAttribute($product, $attribute_code);
```

**Method 2:**

```
$updater = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$updater->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array( $attribute_code => $value), 0);
```

**Method 3: (fastest)**

```
 $update_resource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_action');
 $update_resource->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array( $attribute_code => $value), 0);
```

All above method are much faster that save the entire product anyway there are some major performance difference:

`Method 1`:

- is the fastest, but required you to load the product.
- **it doesn't trigger the reindex event** (that is why is faster)
- it works in frontend

`Method 2`:

- allows to bulk update product
  (you can pass multiple product and multiple attributes)
- **it triggers the mass action event** and the relative dependent reindex
- it does not work in frontend

`Method 3`:

- it is like method 2, but does not call any other observer/indexer
  (so it is a mixed approach between method 1 and 2)

Method 3 is the more flexible one anyway you'll have to reindex those product/attributes manually. (in order to get them updated on frontend)
It may be useful if you want to update a lot of products fast and then call the reindex at the end.
(if you use method 2 a reindex for each product is called after the update and these multiple calls make the whole process slow)

To manually reindex a single product see the functions provided by *Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer* such as:

- `updateAttribute($attributeCode, $store = null, $productIds = null)`
- `updateProduct($productIds, $store = null)`
- ...

Comment: it would be always better to comment downvote ...

Comment: Just a small note, the $value should be a the value code (integer), not the 'textual' value you see in your interface

Comment: hmmm interesting. Method 2 sounds great, only you have no controll over the 'feedback' what succeeded, what did not? Method 1 is also good. But when I am done updating my loop over data: can I manually kick the reindex maybe to solve this for particulr product ids?

Comment: Strange. using Method 2. I am getting an error unknown filter by column ``` Caught exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.value_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`value_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (entity_type_id=4 AND attribute_id='68' AND entity_id='29')``` not expecting that. Running on 1.9.3.2

Comment: Can you pass `$attribute_code => $value` as a key value pair array? to date I keep getting this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttributeId() on boolean in /var/www/html/shirts/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Action.php:72 `

Comment: Saved me hours of work.

Comment: @snh_nl error comes from missing `)` in questions code. Updated right now.

Comment: I have 20k products, by default all products assigned both websites in multi-store. How can I remove all products from selected one website in multi-store?

Comment: open a new separate question.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

> I'm looking for the fastest and reliable method for mass attribute update

"Mass attribute update" for attributes or products?

Think updating multiple attributes is alread answered, but for products this can be usefull ...

If you want to update products from collection, you should not do this ...

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->setSomeData(...);
    # not here
    $product->save();
}
```

This will dispatch events, rebuild pricerules and indices. With this no events (and some other things) are skipped and is lot faster.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->setSomeData(...);
}
$collection->save();
```

To avoid pricerule updates, you can add ...

```
$product->setIsMassupdate(true);
```

To disable/enable reindex on the fly take a look at this ... https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-ChangeAttributeSet/commit/676f3af77fec880bc64333403675d183e8639fae

```
/**
 * Set indexer modes to manual
 */
private function _storeRealtimeIndexer()
{
    $collection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $process) {
        if($process->getMode() != Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL){
            $this->_index[] = $process->getIndexerCode();
            $process->setData('mode', Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
        }
    }

}
/**
 * Restore indexer modes to realtime an reindex product data
 */
private function _restoreRealtimeIndexer()
{
    $reindexCodes = array(
        'catalog_product_attribute',
        'catalog_product_flat'
    );
    $indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
    foreach ($this->_index as $code) {
        $process = $indexer->getProcessByCode($code);
        if (in_array($code, $reindexCodes)) {
            $process->reindexAll();
        }
        $process->setData('mode', Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
    }
}
```

And also flushing cache before mass (product) update can increase performance ...

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

<sup>Some numbers from debugging here: https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-ChangeAttributeSet/issues/16</sup>

---

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(...)` seems not to be the fastest method ... at least not with mutlistore setup and flat tables turned on ...

- #### `saveAttribute()`

  ```
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  $resource = $product->getResource();
  $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
  $resource->saveAttribute($product, $attributeCode);
  ```

  - Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 437,787 microsecs
  - Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  423,600 microsecs
  - Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   4,433,848 bytes
  - Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   4,395,128 bytes
  - Number of Function Calls: 25,711
- #### `updateAttributes()`

  ```
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
      array($productId),
      array($attributeCode => $attributeValue),
      $storeId
  );
  ```

  - Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 3,676,950 microsecs
  - Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  3,122,064 microsecs
  - Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   8,174,792 bytes
  - Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   8,199,192 bytes
  - Number of Function Calls: 150,132
- #### `updateAttributes()` (resource singleton)

  ```
  Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
      array($productId),
      array( $attributeCode => $attributeValue),
      $storeId
  );
  ```

  - Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 94,155 microsecs
  - Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  48,568 microsecs
  - Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   1,426,304 bytes
  - Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   1,370,456 bytes
  - Number of Function Calls: 2,221

Comment: you may review my answer to understand why those function takes different times ...

Comment: For dropdown data does `updateAttributes() (resource singleton)` take the actual admin value? or the id of the dropdown element? (somehow we always get no value/empty value using this method ie nothing selected

Comment: @snh_nl you have to use the ID - comma seperated for multiselect attributes.