# Bulk adding & updating product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, sql

[M1]

I have over 2000 products in my Magento store. I want to add a new attribute called 'Warranty Terms' to display it on the frontend. This is going to be the same for all products. I know how to add a new attribute, but how do I mass update it for all products? Warranty terms attribute is going to require WYSIWYG editor.

I added a new attribute & tried bulk updating it through Catalog > Products > Select All > Update attributes, however, this new attribute is not displaying in the list of attributes that could be mass updated. Is there a way using codes or maybe through SQL query?

Comment: @mihit You can try by importing CVS file just add 2 values one sku and another that new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Why its not showing on list of attributes for mass update?
Try re-index and clean cache, also check is your attribute added to all attribute sets.

If you want do this programaticaly check:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664957/mass-update-of-product-attribute-text

[Magento : Fastest way to update a product attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21150/magento-fastest-way-to-update-a-product-attribute)

Comment: Hi,

I don't know why it's not showing in the list for a mass update. I tried everything - reindexing, clearing cache, etc. but somehow it refused to show in the list. It is added to all attribute sets. That is actually my major issue, otherwise, I know the procedure to mass update attributes.

Comment: What if you select one product?